# C# - Is Statement in Switch Statement

Tags: c#, .net, switch-statement

I need to check if a large number of controls contain values or whether they have been left blank.

I was hoping to do something like this:

```
public static bool IsObjectEmpty(Control ctrlThis)
    {
        switch (ctrlThis)
        {
            case ctrlThis is TextBox:
                TextBox txtThis = (TextBox)ctrlThis;
                if (txtThis.Text == "" || txtThis.Text == null)
                { return false; }
                break;

            case (ctrlThis is ComboBox):
                ComboBox cboThis = (ComboBox)ctrlThis;
                if (cboThis.SelectedValue == -1)
                { return false; }
                break;

            case (ctrlThis is NumericUpDown):
                NumericUpDown numThis = (NumericUpDown)ctrlThis;
                if (numThis.Value == 0)
                { return false; }
                break;

            etc etc...
```

But this doesn't compile:

```
 Error  3   A switch expression or case label must be a bool, char, string,    
 integral, enum, or corresponding nullable type
```

Is there a way of doing this in a switch statement, or am I just gonna have to do a load of if / else if stuff? Google and StackOverflow searches haven't turned up much of any use.

Answer (score 2):

`Case` labels can contains *only* constant expression.

so in your answer is is not a const expression.

it is an evaluated value.

just as much as you can't do

`public const int a=Enumerable.Range(0,2).First();`

you can calc those value before the switch case

and then compare them to a value.

something like

`var t=(ctrlThis is ComboBox)`

```
...
...

switch ( t) ...

case  true :...
```

## edit:from the CLS

```
switch-label:
    case constant-expression :
    default :
```

if you dont do it like that the compiler will scream :

> A constant value is expected

example :

```
switch (myInt)
{
case (2+Enumerable.Range(0,2).First()):
    return true;
    default:
    return true;
}
```

Comment: This is the cause of the error, but not really an answer to the question.

Comment: @RoyiNamir hmm..you are right..need to check out the CLS..and to be clear i didnt downvote you..+1

Answer (score 2):

Conditions (if/switch) based on type are mostly a bad idea.

How about this approach:

```
public static bool IsObjectEmpty(TextBox ctrlThis)
{
    if (ctrlThis.Text == "" || ctrlThis.Text == null) {
        return false;
    }

    etc etc...
}            

public static bool IsObjectEmpty(ComboBox ctrlThis)
{
    if (ctrlThis.SelectedValue == -1) {
        return false;
    }

    etc etc...
}            

public static bool IsObjectEmpty(NumericUpDown ctrlThis)
{
    if (ctrlThis.Value == 0) {
        return false;
    }

    etc etc...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
switch (ctrlThis.GetType().ToString())
{
    case "System.Windows.Forms.TextBox" :
            TextBox txtThis = (TextBox)ctrlThis;
                if (txtThis.Text == "" || txtThis.Text == null)
                { return false; }
                break;
}
```

Comment: However, this would be unsafe if the type ever gets renamed - your solution would still compile, but never reach the handler. A typical `is`-query would not compile anymore, as the type would not be known anymore.

Comment: @AlexanderWeinert You are correct. But if the switch only check systems types and you want an exact type match it would be quite safe.

Answer (score 1):

I might go for if-statements aswell, such as:

```
    public static bool IsObjectEmpty(Control ctrlThis)
    {
        if (ctrlThis is TextBox)
        {
            TextBox txtThis = (TextBox)ctrlThis;
            if (txtThis.Text == "" || txtThis.Text == null)
                return false;
        }
        else if (ctrlThis is ComboBox)
        {
            ComboBox cboThis = (ComboBox)ctrlThis;
            if (int.Parse(cboThis.SelectedValue.ToString()) == -1)
                return false;
        }
        else if (ctrlThis is NumericUpDown)
        {
            NumericUpDown numThis = (NumericUpDown)ctrlThis;
            if (numThis.Value == 0)
                return false;
        }
        else
        {
            //Serves as 'default' in the switch
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can do it like this

```
public static bool IsObjectEmpty(Control ctrlThis)
{
    Type t = ctrlThis.GetType();
    switch (t)
    {
        case typeof(TextBox):
            TextBox txtThis = (TextBox)ctrlThis;
            if (txtThis.Text == "" || txtThis.Text == null)
            { return false; }
            break;
    }
}
```